# Using Choropleth with Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, raphael, cartography

I am currently trying to implement a simple choropleth map into my map (using google maps api v3). I will later on be using either xml or json to retrieve my data but at the moment I am just trying to use hardcoded data. It worked on V2 API google maps but not on the v3. I am not sure what im doing wrong. My code is below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initialize() {

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.500152, -0.126236);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);


  var cartographer = Cartographer( map, { colorize:"#000", colorizeAlpha:.3 } );
cartographer.choropleth([
  {region:"US-MN",val:6},
  {region:"US-IA",val:10},
  {region:"US-WI",val:8},
  {region:"US-SD",val:7},
  {region:"US-ND",val:9},
  {region:"US-MI",val:12}
], { colorScheme:"BuPu"});

    }

     function codeAddress() {
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="London">
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress()">
<div id="map" style="height:100%;top:0px"></div>
   </body>
```

If you know of an alternative method I could use (but with google maps API v3 as a background) please let me know I would be willing to look into it and give it a try.

I have already imported raphael and cartography libraries in the code.

Thanks

ADDITION:

The style ive used along with the div is as follows:

```
   <style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map { height: 100% }
</style>
```

making any changes to that doesnt display my map :(

Comment: What specifically is not working? What is the URL you are using to load the Google Maps API?

Comment: i used the v3 api from the tutorial. the colouring of the cholorpleth doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your are setting the `height` property of the `DIV` that contains the map to `100%`. Try using a specific height. As mentioned in the [Map DOM Elements section of the Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Map_DOM_Elements), you should provide specific sizing style rules for the `DIV` containing the Map or the overall container `DIV`, if your map `DIV` is within a larger `DIV`.

I have had good results using a CSS `width: 100%`, but have had trouble when using `height: 100%`.

Comment: my maps displays fine either way. I tried changing my height to width and set it as u suggested. The map still displays but no colouring on the map :/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Cartography library is not used in conjunction with Google Maps API V3 but only V2 so I will have to use a different method.

Thanks anyways.